# How do you get $(-1)^n$ when you have $e^{in\pi}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

I am having a problem understanding this.

In which cases can you turn $e^{in\pi}$ in to $(-1)^{n}$?

What happens when it instead is $e^{-in\pi}$?

Comment: This works when $n$ is an integer.  Otherwise it depends on your definition of $(-1)^n$; for example think about $n=\frac13$

Comment: Do you knwo that $e^{i\pi}=-1$?

Comment: Do you know the formula $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have added another question.

Comment: $e^{-in\pi} = \overline {e^{in\pi}}$ using the complex conjugate, and since $|e^{in\pi}| =1$ you have $e^{-in\pi} = \frac{1}{e^{in\pi}}$.  So $e^{-in\pi}$ is also $(-1)^n$  when $n$ is an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z\in\Bbb C$ and $n\in\Bbb Z$, then $e^{nz}=(e^z)^n$. So$$(\forall n\in\Bbb Z):e^{\pi in}=(e^{\pi i})^n=(-1)^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using euler`s identity $e^{i\pi}=-1$ and $(e^{i\pi})^{n}=(-1)^{n}$

Comment: So are you saying $(-1)^{1/3}\not=-1$?

Comment: it has 3 different solutions, -1 is one of them.

Comment: But $e^{i\pi/3}$ is a different one and functions are supposed to give a single value

Comment: that's not right. It's like a second grade ecuation has 2 solutions. You should read the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: You said $(e^{i\pi})^{n}=(-1)^{n}$, but now seem to be suggesting "$=$" means something weaker